# Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree inside tab view that inside another tab view

Tags: flutter

I have a `TabBar()` on the main screen in `home.dart`.
In `home.dart` I use `ExtendedTabBarView()` that works properly,
but now in the second tab in home page tab bar view I need another `TabBarView()` which means:

1. tab1
2. tab2
3. tab3

These above are home page tab, in tab2 I need another 2 tab:

1. tab2subtab1
2. tab2subtab2

Now when I take another `ExtendedTabBarView()` it gave me the following  error:

```
 Failed assertion: line 1588 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true.
```

and also:

```
Another exception was thrown: Duplicate Global Keys detected in widget tree.
```

I'm using Global Keys for calling function from homepage

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give a precise answer without looking at the code but you may check if you have defined multiple `GlobalKey()` objects in the same state. If so, separating each subtree requiring a global key into separate widgets will help.